# I am writing a VBA code to copy a cell value to new cell in other sheet and getting error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim Year, Month, lasrow1
  lasrow1 = Sheets("bb").Cells.Find("*", [B1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
  Year = Sheets("aa").Range("C2").Value         
  Month = Sheets("aa").Range("C3").Value           
  '----ERROR IN LINE BELOW---
  Sheets("bb").Range(Cells(lasrow1 + 1, "B")).Value = Year
  '--------------------------
  Sheets("bb").Range(Cells(lasrow1 + 1, "C")).Value = Month      
  Sheets("aa").Select   
  ActiveSheet.Next.Select    
End Sub
```

I am getting error in `Sheets("bb").Range(Cells(lasrow1 + 1, "B")).Value = Year`
I am trying to copy a cell value (named as year) to other sheet after finding the last row of that sheet.

Comment: try... Sheets("bb").Range(Cells(lasrow1 + 1, 2)).Value = Year

Comment: and then to preempt the next error the next line needs to be Sheets("bb").Range(Cells(lasrow1 + 1, 3)).Value = Month

Answer (score 0):

Change below

```
Sheets("bb").Range(Cells(lasrow1 + 1, "B")).Value = Year
Sheets("bb").Range(Cells(lasrow1 + 1, "C")).Value = Month
```

To

```
Sheets("bb").Range(Cells(lasrow1 + 1, 2)).Value = Year
Sheets("bb").Range(Cells(lasrow1 + 1, 3)).Value = Month
```

Using the cells method expects column numbers not letters

Answer (score 0):

Another way, is using [`Range` object and `Offset` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx).

> Range.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)

```
lastrow1 = lastrow1 + 1

'--assuming you are starting at B1 cell, then go down
'--the same column until your desired row
Sheets("bb").Range("B1").Offset(lastrow1,0).Value = Year
Sheets("bb").Range("C1").Offset(lastrow1,0).Value = Month
```